# Index email with ElasticSearch - mapping problem

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I use ES v7. I want to index email address with ElasticSearch but using uax_url_email tokenizer.
I want to search Elastic with full email address.

I tried use this mapping:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": 1,
          "patterns": [
            "([^@]+)",
            "(\\p{L}+)",
            "(\\d+)",
            "@(.+)",
            "([^-@]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "email": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "email",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "emails": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "email"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but get error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse value [1] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse value [1] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

what is wrong with it ? How this mapping should look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is malformed, you are passing `1` to `preserve_original` param which accepts only `true` and `false` as mentioned in the exception.

Apart from this, there are few more issues, like you are using `String` data type which is deprecated in v7.1 and `emails` is coming before `properties` in your JSON.

Correct mapping tested in my local would like

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": true,
                    "patterns": [
                        "([^@]+)",
                        "(\\p{L}+)",
                        "(\\d+)",
                        "@(.+)",
                        "([^-@]+)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "email": {
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
                    "filter": [
                        "email",
                        "lowercase",
                        "unique"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "email": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "email"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You.

I inserted few emails to index with this corrected mapping.

Now when I search for specific email I get all result.
I want to have only one record. How can I do this ?

```
http://localhost:9200/test/_search?q=email:abc@abc.net

{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.21149008,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "0IWQlXcBnPuV0JvQXCHW",
        "_score": 0.21149008,
        "_source": {
          "email": "abc@abc.net"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "0oWUlXcBnPuV0JvQISFe",
        "_score": 0.21149008,
        "_source": {
          "email": "abc1@abc.net"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "z4WQlXcBnPuV0JvQNCGn",
        "_score": 0.19982167,
        "_source": {
          "email": "abc2@abc.net"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "0YWQlXcBnPuV0JvQdiHo",
        "_score": 0.19982167,
        "_source": {
          "email": "abc3@abc.net"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```